# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException while running jdbc program?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have recently started learning JDBC and write a program to create table in a MySQL database, but bad luck I am getting some error or may be exceptions which I am unable to figure it out on my own.
I am just a beginner so please help me to get if of this rid.

Below is the program I have written:

```
package first;
import java.sql.*;
public class Firstclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String JDBC_URL=" jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodatabase";
        String user_name="root";
        String password="toor";
        String sqlquery="create table employee(eno number,ename varchar2(10),esal number(10,2),addr varchar2(10))";
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL,user_name,password);
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(sqlquery);
        System.out.println("Table created Successfully");
        con.close();
    }

}
```

I am working on Eclipse IDE.
And i have oracle java 14.0.1 installed.

Below is the error/Exceptions I get:

```
loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodatabase
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at first.Firstclass.main(Firstclass.java:14)
```

Comment: So... did you install the mySQL JDBC driver, or did you just start typing from a tutorial?

Comment: @MarsAtomic i downloaded a zip and extract it and then while creating project add the .jar file i class path. is it not enough. What you mean by installing mySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: That's what I mean by installing the driver. Make sure to close and reopen your console after messing with your environment variables, and make sure your URL is correct.

Comment: @MarsAtomic i have done it approx 15-20 times and make 15-20 projects just to execute this program but at last i am getting is failure...Sorry

Comment: Well, those are the usual solutions to this error. What version of the driver are you using? Where did you download it? Also, change your `driver` string to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` to get rid of that message before the exception.

Comment: @MarsAtomic i have mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar and i have downloaded it in download directory and extract it in download directory it self...and after posting question here i have changed driver string.

Comment: OK, are you coding this in a text editor or and IDE?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Eclipse IDE

Comment: You have a space before the `jdbc:mysql:....` url, remove that space (that is, the line `String JDBC_URL=" jdbc:mysql:..."` should be `String JDBC_URL="jdbc:mysql:...`). Voting to close as a  typo.

Answer (score 0):

The driver class name was changed to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` in the version that you are using. Since you are trying this out with pure java without maven or gradle you will have to provide all the dependent jars that you are using for this to work yourself. Check the following:

- For your version of the connector `mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar` 
  to work, the java version needs to be java8.
- Verify that  Protocol Buffers and Simple Logging Facade API are on the classpath if you are building from source.

> You may also need to install the following third-party libraries on
>   your system for Connector/J 8.0 to work:
>       Protocol Buffers (required for using X DevAPI)\
>       Simple Logging Facade API (required for using the logging capabilities provided by the default implementation of
>   org.slf4j.Logger.Slf4JLogger by Connector/J) .
>   These and other third-party libraries are required for building
>   Connector/J from source (see the section for more information on the
>   required libraries).

Also, in the MySql docs they suggest we call newInstance() like this (the documentation doesn't have proper explanation for this) :

```
public class LoadDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
            // broken Java implementations

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Official [doc link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing.html#connector-j-third-party-libs)

Also, since java 6 we need not provide the `Class.forName()` to load the driver because of the java SPI (Service Provider Interface) mechanism which should automatically detect the appropriate driver. It will still work perfectly even if you provide it like the old way.

> The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been
>   enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider
>   mechanism.

Java [official link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

Comment: @deep Yes try using this with maven, so that maven will essentially resolve all the necessary dependencies for you. The steps are provided in the doc link in the answer. Otherwise just set the class path for the third party jars as well after downloading them and then try again.

Comment: This is not the actual problem of the question, you are focusing on the warning, not the error. The actual problem is that the JDBC URL starts with a space.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel When he initially posted the question he was using the old driver name with the new jar version he was using, which was causing the issue. But I actually missed that ! Thank you for pointing it out !

Comment: That doesn't matter, loading the old driver classname **still works** with the latest version of the driver; it will also print out a **warning** that that name is deprecated and that you should switch to the new one. This **warning** is not an error: the driver gets loaded, and works. See its source: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/legacy/java/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.java: it extends the new driver class. So loading it will 1) trigger the load of the **new driver** and 2) print the **warning**. In other words, the problem is solely the whitespace.